# Why does my program give "NULL used in arithmetic"

Tags: c++, string

I wrote the following;

```
string words;
int a=0;
getline(cin,words);

while(words[a]!=NULL)
{                           
     a++;                    
}        
cout<<a<<endl;
```

It worked correctly, but when I added the line at the end:

```
string words;
int a=0;
getline(cin,words);

while(words[a]!=NULL)
{
      a++;                       
}
cout<<a<<endl;

if(words[1]=="a") {cout<<"the letter is a";}
```

It no longer works.  Why?

Comment: Is this an *error* or a *warning*? (It sounds like a friendly warning) What is the *exact* text and from which compiler/environment? What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Please do not compare a character to NULL. Use c == 0 or c == '\0', instead. Also: Start counting from zero (`words[0]=='a'`)

Comment: its a warning..i am using bloodshed dev cpp

Comment: Bloodshed is just an IDE that invokes some other toolchain (usually some version of MinGW GCC, I think).  It would be good to know the version of the compiler being used in your Bloodshed install.  Also, as a general rule you should copy/paste the error message you're getting into the question.

Answer (score 11):

In the line

```
   while(words[a]!=NULL)
```

`NULL` is used not as a pointer but as `0`.

It works since `word[a]` evaluates to a `char` and you can compare a `char` with `0`.

In the line

```
if(words[1]=="a")
```

it fails because you are trying to compare `char` with `"a"`, whose type is `char const*`.

You probably meant to use:

```
if(words[1]=='a')
```

Answer (score 5):

Replace the double quote `""` by single quote `''` in `if` conditional expression. Note that `NULL` macro is used for null pointer constant not for null constant `\0`.

```
while(words[a]! = '\0')
{
      cout<<a<<endl;
      a++;                     
}       

if(words[1] == 'a')
    cout<<"the letter is a";
```

Comment: The latter (`NUL`) is not defined in C++.  Just write `'\0'` when you want a nul character, `0` when you want an integer 0, `0.0` when you want a floating point 0, and `NULL` (or `nullptr` if you have C++11) when you want a pointer.

Comment: @JamesKanze; In C, `NUL` is defined. I was not aware about C++. Thanks.

Comment: `NUL` is not defined in C either - it might be for you from a non-standard header or as an extension in the toolchain you're using.

Comment: @MichaelBurr; Interesting. I just searched C11 standard and found nothing about `NUL` except in foot note 199: *In an implementation that uses the seven-bit US ASCII character set, the printing characters are those
whose values lie from 0x20 (space) through 0x7E (tilde); the control characters are those whose
values lie from 0 (`NUL`) through 0x1F (US), and the character 0x7F (DEL).`*

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
 words[a]
```

the result is a char, which can be implicitly converted into an int and compared to NULL (same as 0)

When you say

```
 words[1]=="a"
```

you are trying to compare a char to a char*, which will fail

you have to convert the left side to a string or the right side to a char

```
  'a' is the equivalent char to the right side
```

the other way is

```
  words.substr(1, 1) == " a "
```

that gives you the substring starting from position 1 and length 1...

By doing that you are now comparing string to char*, which is possible because char* will be implicitly converted to string.